# How to increase images size by some value?

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

Ok so I'm working with couple images on HTML.
Let me give the example how they place!

```
image 1 <img src=".." width="500" />
image 2 <img src=".."  width="540"/>
image 3 <img src=".."  width="490"/>
image 4 <img src=".."  width="550"/>
.
.And so on.
```

for some reason i need to increase the size of the image by some value (scaling image) like width="500 + some value"

If i use

```
img {
width:40% or 550px;
height:auto; }
```

// It scale all the image and distube the images ratio(they are text screenshots thats why!)

Can anyone give me some code to increase all images size by some value?
It can be javascript also!

help fast!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do it like this

```
var img = document.getElementById("id of your image goes here");
if(img && img.style){
    img.style.height = "insert_num_herepx";
    img.style.width = "insert_num_herepx";
}
```

[example](https://jsfiddle.net/bjskistad/c9o9h9e5/)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, `<img>` tag is an inline element, it's recommended to be inside a block element like a `<div>` element. Set either `className` or `id` for those img elements. To retrieve the current tag dimension, use window.getComputedStyle, below is the code that demonstrates it.

JS:

```
function Scale(width_offset, height_offset) {
   var imgs = document.getElementsByClassName("your img tag class name");
   for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
     var curr_width = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(imgs[i]).width);
     var curr_height = parseInt(window.getComputedStyle(imgs[i]).height);
     imgs[i].style.width = curr_width + width_offset + "px";
     imgs[i].style.height = curr_height + height_offset + "px";
   }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure where you got the "it's recommended that inline elements be inside block elements" from. Also, you are using outdated terms for the content models. These days it should be "phrasing" and "flow" instead of "inline" and "block". The latter are now reserved solely for CSS `display` values!

Comment: I believe it's about syntax style issues because it's what I was taught while in school; and I just took that class about few months ago. Thanks for the info. :)